# Inherit example in nested Rspec contexts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

How can you reuse the examples so that you only override the details on nested contexts?

Something like this (I use `thee` instead of it that indicates that it is executed in nested context. It is NOT in RSpec, just what I want):

```
describe "Abilities" do
  subject { Abilities.new user }

  context "allowed" do
    let(:user) { Factory(:power_user) }
    thee { should be_able_to :create, object }
    thee { should be_able_to :read, object }
    thee { should be_able_to :update, object }

    context "comment" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:comment) }
    end

    context "post" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:post) }
    end

    context "blog" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:blog) }
    end

  end
end
```

This example would end up with 3 examples (create, read, update) for 3 contexts (comment, post, blog) resulting in 9 examples in total.

How is it possible to achieve it (without writing shared examples)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a way to inherit the examples but you can make a class method:

```
describe "Abilities" do
  subject { Abilities.new user }

  def self.should_allow_stuff
    it { should be_able_to :create, object }
    it { should be_able_to :read, object }
    it { should be_able_to :update, object }
  end

  context "allowed" do
    let(:user) { Factory(:power_user) }

    context "comment" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:comment) }
      should_allow_stuff
    end

    context "post" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:post) }
      should_allow_stuff
    end

    context "blog" do
      let(:object) { Factory(:blog) }
      should_allow_stuff
    end

  end
end
```

You can refactor as necessary if you like.

Comment: Note: I do not recommend this way of sharing examples anymore. Shared contexts in RSpec now live inside of contexts and do not bleed out into the global scope, so you should use those instead. Alternatively, because shared examples can be confusing to run independently and difficult to debug, I would look into building your own matchers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to write shared examples? This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: Writing shared examples feels like overkill here. There are many situations like this where shared examples would be applied only once. Thus those shared examples are not shared at all.

Comment: If shared examples weren't kept globally then I would say use them, but since they're not (at least last time I checked), I agree they're a bit overkill.